# Python regex for getting string with special characters

Tags: python, regex

So i want to get specific data

So string is an input by the user

```
"price_to_earning + current_price * 0.8"
```

It could even be

```
"price_to_earning*current_price+0.8"
```

or

```
"price_to_earning *current_price/0.8"
```

How can i extract just `"price_to_earning" & "current_price"` from the above

currently, I'm using

```
    words = re.findall(r"\b\S+", raw_query)
```

but it gets

```
['price_to_earning', 'current_price', '0.8']
```

what I want is

```
['price_to_earning', 'current_price']
```

Comment: maybe try this? \b[^\r\n\t\f\v [0-9.]]+

Comment: Using regex to parse mathematical expressions is misdirected. You want to cope with arbitrary nesting of parentheses; use a proper parser instead. This is a common FAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a regex to match words without digits, e.g. `[^\d\W]+` ?

have a look at the demo here
https://regex101.com/r/EbNQvm/1

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the characters you want to exclude, and replace everything else with a space, for example -

```py
s1 = "price_to_earning + current_price * 0.8"
s2 = "price_to_earning*current_price+0.8"
s3 = "price_to_earning *current_price/0.8"
for s in [s1, s2, s3]:
    print(re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z_]', ' ', s).split())
```

**Output**

```
['price_to_earning', 'current_price']
['price_to_earning', 'current_price']
['price_to_earning', 'current_price']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try finding only characters and _

`words = re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z_]+", raw_query)`